# Read chunk of data from a file using java 8

Tags: java, file-read

I need to read a text file using java 8. I can read the entire file. But my problem is how can I read only a part of the file.

Example: 
I need to read data in between `{AAAA} {/AAAA}`. How can I do this using java 8 and older versions?

```
{AAAA}
This is the detailed description. This needs to be printed in the book
{/AAAA}
{BBBB}
Sample Code 1
Sample Code 2
Sample Code 3
{/BBBB}
```

Comment: read the file line by line until you find what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to read your file line by line until you reach your patterns by doing something like that:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(new File(file), charset))
 ) {
    String line;
    boolean start = false;
    // Read the file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (start) {
            // Here the start pattern has been found already
            if (line.equals("{/AAAA}")) {
                // The end pattern has been reached so we stop reading the file
                break;
            }
            // The line is not the end pattern so we treat it
            doSomething(line);
        } else {
            // Here we did not find the start pattern yet
            // so we check if the line is the start pattern
            start = line.equals("{AAAA}");
        }
    }
}
```

This way you only read your file until you reach the end pattern which will be more efficient than reading the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 9 (still in beta), you could write something like:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, UTF_8)) {
  result = lines.dropWhile(line -> !line.equals("{AAAA}")
                .takeWhile(line -> !line.equals("{/AAAA}")
                .collect(toList());
}
```

With Java 8 or earlier, a standard while loop seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(myFile)));
  while(!((content=br.readLine()).equals("{/AAAA}")))
  {
     System.out.println(content);
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Files.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) or [`Files.lines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) to get all lines streamed.

The reading mechanism - e.g. reading all lines from "{AAAA}" till "{/AAAA}" must be implemented by you.

Comment: Starting/ending based on a condition won't be easy with Java 8 streams (it will get better with Java 9 using dropWhile / takeWhile)...